# Scrapy : Sending information to prior function

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy 1.1 to scrape a website. The site requires periodic relogin. I can tell when this is needed because when login is required a 302 redirection occurs. Based on # http://sangaline.com/post/advanced-web-scraping-tutorial/ , I have subclassed the RedirectMiddleware, making the location http header available in the spider under:

```
request.meta['redirect_urls']
```

My problem is that after logging in , I have set up a function to loop through 100 pages to scrape . Lets say after 15 pages I see that I have to log back in (based on the contents of request.meta['redirect_urls']) . My code looks like:

```
def test1(self, response):

    ......
    for row in empties: # 100 records
        d = object_as_dict(row)

        AA

        yield Request(url=myurl,headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_lookup, meta={d':d}, dont_filter=True)

def parse_lookup(self, response):

    if 'redirect_urls' in response.meta:
        print str(response.meta['redirect_urls'])

        BB

    d = response.meta['d']
```

So as you can see, I get 'notified' of the need to relogin in parse_lookup at BB , but need to feed this information back to cancel the loop creating requests in test1 (AA). How can I make the information in parse lookup available in the prior callback function?

Comment: Raise an Exception at the called function and use a `try` block in the calling function. Exceptions are not just for exceptional things in Python, I dare to say they are a sugarcoated GOTO. You can also try to write your own [retry decorator](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/).

Comment: Paulo, would you mind showing a code sample, I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I'm at work right now, that is why I just commented instead of posting a proper answer. I can try to write a full answer later.

Comment: I've added a bounty on this , because I think its an important question.

Comment: @PauloScardine , do you mind taking a look at the question again? I was interested in your try block concept.

Comment: Now that I have read your question more carefully, I see we can't catch an `Exception` raised at `parse_lookup` in the `test1` loop because `parse_lookup` is not being called there, it is just being set as the callback for the `Request` object - so I was wrong, my first comment is not useful for your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a DownloaderMiddleware?

You could write a DownloaderMiddleware like so:

Edit: I have edited the original code to address a second problem the OP had in the comments.

```
from scrapy.http import Request

class CustomMiddleware():

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if 'redirect_urls' in response.meta:
            # assuming your spider has a method for handling the login
            original_url = response.meta["redirect_urls"][0]
            return Request(url="login_url", 
                           callback=spider.login, 
                           meta={"original_url": original_url})
        return response
```

So you "intercept" the response before it goes to the parse_lookup and relogin/fix what is wrong and yield new requests...

Like Tomáš Linhart said the requests are asynchronous so I don't know if you could run into problems by "reloging in" several times in a row, as multiple requests might be redirected at the same time.

Remember to add the middleware to your settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': 542,
    'myproject.middlewares.CustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm now running into a problem because I have the spider set up with a login function at the beginning and I need to redirect to this function. In other words:  yield Request(url=response.meta["redirect_urls"][0], callback=my_spider.my_login_function(my_spider(),response)). How do you redirect the newly created request to the correct login function?

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. Do you want to, on the middleware yield a Request to the login method and pass the redirected url?

Comment: Basically yes, I've been trying to import the spider class into the middleware to be able to redirect the new request to the correct callback function.

Comment: I have never actually done that, it should be very straight forward but I am not able to test at the moment. You could try this tho: yield Request(url="login_url", callback=spider.my_login_function, meta={"redirect_url": response.meta["redirect_urls"][0]})

Comment: Thanks when I do that I get : TypeError: unbound method my_login() must be called with My_spider instance as first argument (got HtmlResponse instance instead)

Comment: I have edited the code in the answer, it should suffice your needs. I also apologize for I forgot a few things in the code I gave you before, return rather than yield and the self param

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve what you want because Scrapy uses asynchronous processing.

In theory you could use approach partially suggested in comment by @Paulo Scardine, i.e. raise an exception in `parse_lookup`. For it to be useful, you would then have to code your spider middleware and handle this exception in [`process_spider_exception`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.SpiderMiddleware.process_spider_exception) method to log back in and retry failed requests.

But I think better and simpler approach would be to do the same once you detect the need to login, i.e. in `parse_lookup`. Not sure exactly how `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` works, but setting this to `1` might let you process one request at time and so there should be no failing requests as you always log back in when you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Don't iterate over the 100 items and create requests for all of them. Instead, just create a request for the first item, process it in your callback function, yield the item, and only after that's done create the request for the second item and yield it. With this approach, you can check for the location header in your callback and either make the request for the next item or login and repeat the current item request.

For example:

```
def parse_lookup(self, response):
    if 'redirect_urls' in response.meta:
        # It's a redirect
        yield Request(url=your_login_url, callback=self.parse_login_response, meta={'current_item_url': response.request.url}
    else:
        # It's a normal response
        item = YourItem()
        ...  # Extract your item fields from the response
        yield item
        next_item_url = ...  # Extract the next page URL from the response
        yield Request(url=next_item_url, callback=self.parse_lookup)
```

This assumes that you can get the next item URL from the current item page, otherwise just put the list of URLs in the first request's META dict and pass it along.

Comment: "and only after that's done create the request for the second item and yield it. " : could you show some code on how you would do this?

Comment: Added an example. The trick is basically yielding both an item and a request, Scrapy will know how to handle each one.

Comment: Thanks, did not know you could have 2 yields in the same function

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be better not to try all 100 requests all at once, instead you should try to "serialize" the requests, for example you could add all your `empties` in the request's `meta` and pop them out as necessary, or put the `empties` as a field of your spider.

Another alternative would be to use the [scrapy-inline-requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy-inline-requests) package to accomplish what you want, but you should probably extend your middleware to perform the login.

Comment: "or put the empties as a field of your spider" - What do you mean by this?

Comment: Let's assume it's a list of objects, if you set it as a `deque` in some method like `self.empties = deque(empties)` then in your `parse_lookup` you could try to do a `self.empties.popleft()` (checking if there's any to be popped) and  queue the next request accordingly

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean , but don't you still have to loop through them ?